# How to use multiple service accounts with gcloud?

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

I have two Google Cloud service accounts; one for each of my two projects.

```
# ACCOUNTS
editor@someproj-1.iam.gserviceaccount.com
editor@someproj-2.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

I can tell `gcloud` which account I need to use before executing a command:

```
gcloud set account [ACCOUNT]
```

**Question:** Is there any way I can configure `gcloud` and `gsutil` so that they'll be used for operations performed in their respective project without me having to switch between these accounts manually all the time?

---

I'm managing instances in one project and I upload/download files from buckets in another project. It becomes quite tedious to have to perform `gcloud set_account [ACCOUNT]` all the time in-between commands.

I need to be running long-running commands in both projects at the same time which causes me to think I will fall into a pit if I activate/de-activate the accounts used for these commands.

Perhaps my only option is to run google-cloud-sdk from two different Docker containers?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You have several options here:

- The Cloud SDK respects environment variables specifying properties. `gcloud config set account` is shorthand for `gcloud config set core/account`, so the corresponding property is `CLOUDSDK_CORE_ACCOUNT`.

  You can do something like:

  ```
  $ CLOUDSDK_CORE_ACCOUNT=email1@domain1.com gcloud ...
  $ CLOUDSDK_CORE_ACCOUNT=email2@domain2.com gcloud ...
  ```

  Which should get you the result you're interested in.
- If you need more than one property changed, the Cloud SDK offers a [named configuration](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/configurations) abstraction. See the docs for full details, but you can run:

  ```
  $ gcloud config configurations create my-project1-config
  $ gcloud config configurations activate my-project1-config
  $ gcloud auth login  # or activate-service-account
  $ gcloud config set project project1  # and any other configuration you need to do
  $ 
  $ gcloud config configurations create my-project2-config
  $ gcloud config configurations activate my-project2-config
  $ gcloud auth login  # or activate-service-account
  $ gcloud config set project project2  # and any other configuration you need to do
  $
  $ CLOUDSDK_ACTIVE_CONFIG_NAME=my-project1-config gcloud ...
  $ CLOUDSDK_ACTIVE_CONFIG_NAME=my-project2-config gcloud ...
  ```
- In the most extreme case, you can maintain separate Cloud SDK configuration directories. The default (on *nix) is `~/.config/gcloud`:

  ```
  $ CLOUDSDK_CONFIG=/tmp/tmpconfig1 gcloud auth login
  $ CLOUDSDK_CONFIG=/tmp/tmpconfig2 gcloud auth login
  ```

Comment: To add to this answer, gcloud supports --account and --configuration flags. Possible values for --account can be listed via `gcloud auth list` and possible values for configurations can be listed via `gcloud config configurations list`. But these two flags cannot be used with gsutil or bq.

Comment: Is there a reason I shouldn't check off "_Allow full access to all Cloud APIs_" when I make a new instance?  I found this line in GCloud docs: "_In general, Google recommends that each instance that needs to call a Google API should run as a service account with minimum permissions necessary for that instance to do its job._".  But reading that [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#best_practices), I didn't understand **why** that was recommended

Comment: I have, on the other hand, had the experience where I create an instance, then in like a month or 2 after I've forgotten the details that went into creating it, I want access to some convenient Google API that I then have to "search-engine-around" for the way to grant my service account the permissions for.  So I'm probably gonna go ahead and grant more power than I *need*.  I was mainly concerned about 1. someone getting access to my VM somehow and abusing those permissions, but maybe 2. I might accidentally break something later due to my having more powers than I *needed*

Answer (score 43):

Zachary's answer is pretty useful, but there's an easier way to use gcloud's configurations.

Run `gcloud config configurations list` to display a list of your configurations.  If you haven't made any, it'll just list `default` with whatever your current account, project, etc that are active.

Create a new configuration with `gcloud config configurations create [config name]`:

```
> gcloud config configurations create testconfig
Created [testconfig].
Activated [testconfig].
```

The new configuration will now be active, so go ahead and set it up with `gcloud init`:

```
> gcloud init
Welcome! This command will take you through the configuration of gcloud.
```

It will then ask you a series of questions:

- When it asks you to pick a configuration to use, pick `[1] Re-initialize this configuration [testconfig] with new settings`.
- It will then ask you to choose or log in to an account.
- It will then ask you to choose or create a project.
- Finally, it will ask whether you want to set a default zone for your project.  It's up to you; on projects where everything is in the same zone, go ahead and set it.

```
Your Google Cloud SDK is configured and ready to use!
```

Switch accounts using `gcloud config configurations activate [config name]`.

Comment: Fantastic answer, just what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: This is super straightfoward. This should probably be the new answer.